# How to Add a Signal Boosting Antenna to a Wifi Router that doesn't Have an Antenna off the Shelf?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I have a wifi router that I would like to boost the signal strength to. Off the shelf, it does not have any antennas. However it does have a usb port. According to the manual, that usb port was built with 4g hot spot dongles in mind. I'm not sure if I can re-purpose that usb port by inserting a usb wifi signal booster / adapter.

When I read through the information on usb wifi signal booster products, they typically include a cd rom and require drivers to operate. That leads me to believe that buy going out and buying a usb wifi signal booster and sticking it into the router, the router would not really be able to do anything with it, as routers do not have operating systems. At least that is how it plays out in my mind currently.

So correct me if I'm wrong about anything. Also, if any one does know of a way to attach an antenna to boost wifi signal onto a router (with no antenna) via usb or other means, please suggest specific brands and/or products. Thank you.

In case it's needed for assessment, the brand of my wifi router is the Lenovo stack wifi router. The specs can be seen [here](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/accessories/buythinkpadstack/).

**Note:** I know there may be simpler means of boosting wifi signal like wall adapters with wifi repeaters/boosters. However, I'm asking this question more as a proof of concept. So I'd appreciate a yes or no answer, even if the yes is complicated. Thank you!

Comment: It has to have an antenna, might not be external, if it didn't have one it literally couldn't be a wireless router.  Page you linked to doesn't have a wireless router on it.

Answer (score 3):

Your router will not be able to use any USB wireless cards. Your assumption that they need drivers is correct.

You're best bet would be to Google this. Some string like "add antennas to a [router manufacturer and model]". Several routers have kits on eBay and the like to add antennas yourself ([Linksys](http://www.ebay.com/itm/7dBi-Dual-Band-Antenna-Mod-Kit-Linksys-E3000-amp-WRT610N-/140743705285) routers are especially easy to do, for example). Please note that these require opening the router's case and thereby void the warranty of your device.